# setting baud rate on dial-up connection win32

Tags: winapi, ras, baud-rate

I am creating dial-up connection in code in Windows XP and Windows 7 (RasSetEntryProperties).  The entries come up with the default baud rate of 19200.

Using Win32 how do I change the baud rate in both Windows XP and Windows 7?

Comment: Hmm, no close reason that says "asked 15 years too late" :/  Ask at superuser.com for the phone book.

Comment: It looks like the poster's code is going to be used in 75% of the world that doesn't have wired phone service.  It doesn't look like the code will control elevators or industrial machines because those aren't Ras type stuff.

Comment: talking to legacy equipment, have to use win32 API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the DCB and MaxConnectSpeed in the modem registry entry BEFORE making the RAS entry solves this issue.

Answer (score 0):

SetCommState.  Call GetCommState first so you can preserve other existing settings that you don't want to change.

Comment: Anything done in SetCommState is not used in RasDial()...I think TAPI is the answer.